# Buffer Overflow due to wrong data type

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am reading the [OWASP page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_Overflows) on buffer overflow. It mentions:

*buffer overflow can be prevented using higher-level programming languages that are strongly typed* and

*developer should validate input to prevent unexpected data from being processed, such as of the wrong data type*

Can someone give an example when an incorrect data type can lead to a buffer overflow ?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some C/C++ examples:

- Reading a long into an int memory space (say with scanf).

  ```
  int i;
  scanf("%ld", &i);
  ```
- Using a float as an index in a for loop instead of a fixed point structure, resulting in possibly one more or less iteration than expected.

  ```
  char *arr = new char[9];
  for(float j=1; j>0; j=j-0.1) { // will clobber 10 characters, not 9
      *arr++ = 'A';
  ```
- copying between arrays with different type widths

  ```
  float floatArr[10] = { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
  char charArr[10];
  memcpy(charArr, floatArr, sizeof(float));
  ```

Comment: For the second example, would it be 10 iterations ? I couldn't follow how would there be an extra iteration.

Comment: It's not the number of iterations it's the type used as an index.

Comment: With j=j+1, will float still cause a problem ?

Comment: No ... 1 can be accurately represented as a float.  I have modified the example to be correct.